# Mini Tennis Game using Threads Java

Tags: java, runnable, graphics2d

I am having a some difficulty with developing of my code. Since I am not too advanced with Java I need some help. I am trying to develop Mini Tennis game using Threads. The aim of this game is to catch the balls moving on the window with the paddle that can be controlled with the left and right buttons on the keyboard.

Those balls should move diagonally on the window and when they touch to any of the corner (out of bottom) they should change their ways like light reflection. Apart from this, when a ball touches to one of the obstacles they should change their ways as well.

Paddle on the bottom of the window can be controlled with left and right keys.The task of the player is to catch the balls. The number of balls that the user catches will be shown on the Score part with the total number of balls going to the bottom corner.

User may need to save the state of the game. When the user clicks to the “save game” button; ball locations and score should save to the file. And when the user clicks to the open button, the state of game should be reloaded.

My source code files are:

```
public class BallPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

int RED, GREEN, BLUE;
int Xdirection = 1, Ydirection = 1;
boolean pleaseWait = false;

BallPanel(int X, int Y){
    locateBall(X, Y, 30, 30);               
/*  Random r = new Random();
    RED = r.nextInt(255);
    GREEN = r.nextInt(255);
    BLUE = r.nextInt(255);
    */
}   
public void paint(Graphics g){
    int panelWidth = this.getWidth();
    int panelHeight = this.getHeight();     

//  g.setColor( new Color(RED, GREEN, BLUE ));
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

    g.fillOval(panelWidth/2, panelHeight/2,panelWidth/2, panelHeight/2);
}

public void locateBall(int x, int y, int width, int height){

    setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    repaint();
}

public void run() {

    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();
    Random r = new Random();

    while(true){
        if(!pleaseWait){
            int lastX = this.getX();
            int lastY = this.getY();

            if (lastX > 675) Xdirection = -1;
            if (lastY > 485) Ydirection = -1;
            if (lastX < -5) Xdirection = 1;
            if (lastY < -5) Ydirection = 1;

    /*      if(lastX > 280 && lastY > 170){
                Xdirection = -1;
                Ydirection = -1;
            }
    */      
            locateBall(lastX + Xdirection*r.nextInt(3), 
                       lastY + Ydirection*r.nextInt(3), 
                       width, height );
        }
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }catch(Exception e){};
    }

}

}


public class BallWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton btnStop = new JButton("STOP");
    JButton btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");
    Vector<BallPanel> ballVector = new Vector<BallPanel>();

    JPanel p1 = createPanel(280, 200, 200, 20, Color.gray);
    JPanel p2 = createPanel(280, 300, 200, 20, Color.gray);
    JPanel bottomp = createPanel(345, 540, 70, 15, Color.black);

    JPanel lborder = createPanel(10, 10, 2, 560, Color.black);
    JPanel rborder = createPanel(720, 10, 2, 560, Color.black);
    JPanel tborder = createPanel(10, 10, 710, 2, Color.black);



public BallWindow() {
    setLayout(null);
    btnStop.setBounds(12, 15, 100, 30);
    btnStop.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnStop);
    btnSave.setBounds(12, 50, 100, 30);
    //btnSave.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnSave);
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        BallPanel bp = new BallPanel(r.nextInt(740), r.nextInt(590));
        Thread t = new Thread(bp);
        ballVector.add(bp);
        t.start();
        add(bp);
    }


    add(p1);
    add(p2);
    add(bottomp);
    add(lborder);
    add(rborder);
    add(tborder);

    setSize(740, 590);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    repaint();
}


JPanel createPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color pColor){
    JPanel temp = new JPanel();
    temp.setBackground(pColor);
    temp.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    return temp;    
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BallWindow();

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    for (BallPanel ball : ballVector) {
        ball.pleaseWait = !ball.pleaseWait;
    }

    if( btnStop.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"))
        btnStop.setText("START");
    else
        btnStop.setText("STOP");

//  if(arg0.getSource())

}

}
```

I'm stuck with obstacles part and the keylistener. Any type of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8pyl9x6cib3s4i/1.png?dl=0
Here what i developed so far(i am new here so can't post pictures yet ;))

Comment: That's quite a bit if reading to do... And you never even told us you're problem /: Also, do you even need multiple threads for this? (Other than the EDT and possible game thread)

Comment: Perhaps this is of assistance: https://github.com/m1dnight/JPong

Comment: Yes i am sorry for so much information. Just wanted to make clear what my project is about. My problem is that i dont know how to implement keylistener so while pressing "left" and "right" i will be able to move my bottom panel. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Christopher, thanks for the link. This would be grately useful:)

Answer (score 0):

Hava a look at http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/

You should especially check out the Basics and the Animation section. It will help clean up the animation and thread stuff you are doing. It also shows a general pattern how one could implement a java game.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Is helping me out. I guess i am going to have sleepless night today:)))